# Why should I close a question about a misleading error in development tools?

Tags: discussion, scope

I posed a question over at Stack Overflow: *[Jest failing “due to coverage threshold breaches” without coverage settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57877617/jest-failing-due-to-coverage-threshold-breaches-w-o-coverage-settings)*

I received two votes to close the question as *off-topic* – so I read the guidelines again, and issues with development tools are listed as valid questions for Stack Overflow.

What might their reason be to vote for closing the question? What can I do to make the question more aligned with the guidelines?

The resolution for my issue was that it's a completely misleading error from the development tools, which could be fixed by an unexpected action. I think I would be happy to find this tip when googling the error.

Comment: The close-votes are for "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers". I have no clue about that technology so I can't say if this applies and what is missing.

Comment: You self-answered, so here’s a litmus test: given *only the information available in your question*, would anyone other than you have been able to post an identical answer? Questions are meant to be self-contained and answers conclusive. There is no way to use SO to solicit general pointers or advice or “pick the hive mind”. Questions must stand on their own, and admit definitive answers, so the next guy who comes along has a ready-made solution. If that’s not the case, we devolve back to the old broken conversational forum model SO was explicitly designed to replace.

Comment: "Off-topic" is kind of misleading. It's a general category for questions that don't follow a specific site rule (in this case, that debugging questions have to have enough information for the problem to be clearly identifiable).

Answer (score 8):

Your question falls into the "debugging" category (why I'm getting a particular error) - which requires some sort of MRE. The post was missing any sort of code needed to reproduce the problem and hence got close votes as "missing an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)".

Possible fixes:

- add the example code/configuration. This should be somewhat trivial now when you figured out the problem.
- convert (or merge) the question into a more generic "why I'm getting error XXXX". Note that depending on scope and frequency of the error it may be considered "too broad". Consider similarly "broad" questions like *[What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)* for guidance on the desired quality of such a post.